# cURL causing page to hang

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the current code to attempt to use cURL to asynchronously execute two scripts.  Each script is hosted on a different domain and take ~30 seconds to complete.  I'm wanting these to run in the background so that the page continues to load, but it's hanging until they complete.  Am I completely wrong in my thinking of how cURL works?  Or did I just do something wrong?

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : 'ajax.php?mode=process',
    data    : '$url',
    complete: function(data)
    {
        $('#test'+num).append('Operation successful.');
    }
});
```

Num is the ID of the div.  They're generated through code.  All this works properly, except that cURL locks the server until it's finished processing the files.

The code below is now on another page specifically for processing the URLs passed in from the jQuery ajax call above.

```
$cURLs = array(
    "script_url?param1=1&param2=2",
    "script_url?param1=5&param2=6");
$result = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach ($data as $id => $d) 
{
    $cURLs[$id] = curl_init();
    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($cURLs[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($cURLs[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($cURLs[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if (is_array($d)) 
    {
            if (!empty($d['post'])) 
            {
                    curl_setopt($cURLs[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
                    curl_setopt($cURLs[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
            }
    }

    if (!empty($options))
            curl_setopt_array($cURLs[$id], $options);

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $cURLs[$id]);
}

$running = null;
do 
{
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);

foreach($cURLs as $id => $c) 
{
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($result, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Calling curl is like calling any other function - the script blocks until the function returns. Most functions are near-instantaneous, so you don't notice. curl's entirely dependent on what the remote resource does (and its own timeout parameter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your page will not finish loading until your script finishes executing.  Even if you use cURL Multi functions, that is only good for when the script is running.

If you need a script to run in the background, you must find another method, such as queuing a download job in a database, and cron running a script to check that queue every minute.

Comment: Consider writing a PHP daemon/task or cron script that scans a queue table for files to download, and engineer your A.php page to scan the results saved to the table. Script B.php could be checking the table a few times a minute if necessary. However, you might need many B.php tasks running as each B.php task would not be able to simultaneously service multiple users.

Comment: @memnoch_proxy I'm actually in the middle of doing that now.  Going to have the initial script load up all the variables and save them in my database, then call the script via Ajax.  The script will go through each row in the table, process them and remove them.  At the same time, I'm going to run a small JS on the main page to query the DB every couple of seconds to see if a table disappears.  When it does, that missing table will report back as finished.  Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this as an options for curl request.

```
$CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
);
```

Comment: That's not really the issue here.  The script itself takes around 30 seconds to finish, and I'm calling it about 71 times, which would take about 35 minutes to finish if done synchronously.  It appears to be doing about 6 - 8 files at a time which cuts it down to around 5 minutes total processing time.  However, the server is inaccessible during that time.  No other pages can be loaded while it's processing.  I **need** it to be a background process, which is what I _thought_ cURL would be doing for me.

Comment: This is an example of setting the timeout but does not achieve any parallelism.

Comment: I think you need cron jobs than

Comment: Will the order of the curl option matter ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this asynchronously, you need to complete output to your page, then use JQuery to call a script that loads the data using cURL.

Comment: Why jQuery? why not any library? only jQuery does ajax -- very untrue.

Comment: Have you done this method?  Using jQuery to run a cURL request and have it perform asynchronously?

Comment: @Andrew, he is suggesting that you have a script that does exactly what it does now, but the client page loads and then this script is called with jQuery.  This will work for you, depending on your needs.  Keep in mind that if the client closes connection, PHP is terminated, unless you configure it otherwise in php.ini.

Comment: @Brad Alright, I've invoked $.ajax to pass the URL to another page which does all the cURL work, but it locks my server until it's finished.  The current page updates with all the ajax calls just fine to let me know when each stage is done, but I'm unable to load any other page.  What gives?

Comment: That suggestion could be rephrased: use AJAX calls from A.php to start requests to B.php that actually does the curl downloads.

Comment: @memnoch_proxy That's precisely what I did, but it's not asynchronous.

Comment: Quite true - I just wrote it quickly - I just like JQuery.  If it kills your server, maybe you don't have enough threads handling requests in your Apache setup.  I forget how to configure this.  Each PHP request will use an Apache worker thread and will retain it until complete.  You could set the cURL timeout to restrict duration, or maybe look into why the destination server is taking so long to respond?

Comment: The destination server takes so long due to the particular type of analysis it's doing, there's no way to speed that up.  As for the possibility of it utilizing too many threads, it does this even if I only call it one time.

Comment: @Andrew, you really should be doing this kind of thing as a background task, and displaying the results to your client.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post...but I had a similar issue, and I was able to get around it...not sure if it's the same as yours since you only shared a portion of your code, but I will share this anyway because I found it hard to find the right answer, and it sounds very much like what I was trying to solve:

I had an ajax call, which called a.php, a.php called b.php via the cURL CLI to process the page in the background (using PHP's exec() function) b.php used libcurl to scrape a website...b.php was causing a.php to stop responding to my ajax requests to check the status of the scraper.  I found that the reason was because I was storing information from the scraper into the global $_SESSION var...you cannot read/write to the same session in more than one location, so my periodic ajax requests to a.php (which was using the same session as the cURL scraper on b.php was) were hanging.  Using session_write_close() periodically throughout the cURL scraper caused my ajax requests to not hang because the session is no longer blocking the page requests from going through.

I'd be interested in finding out if this was the reason for your ajax requests hanging until cURL finished processing